# Why can thermal shocks damage/break materials?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, shock-waves

When an object is heated a lot and then brutally cooled down or vice-versa, it can crack or even break spectacularly. What happens inside that makes it do that?

Is it only because the hot core swells when the cold surface shrinks, which causes internal stresses?

Bonus: Are certain materials more sensitive to thermal shocks (high CTE?)?

Comment: What does CTE mean?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Given the context, I think CTE = Coefficient of Thermal Expansion.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/what-pressure-or-tension-occurs-in-a-glass-jar-when-i-pour-boiling-water-inside

Comment: The link by dmckee basically covers it. It'd like to clarify that the hot core is already larger when the cooling starts (question was unclear on this point).

Comment: Thanks dmckee, I hadn't seen that one. So basically there is'nt any other phenomenon other than differential thermal expansion?