# Why can a thermos flask break when washed in cold water?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

My mother and the manual of the thermos flask say to use warm water to wash it and avoid cold water. Why is this? The water isn't even that cold ($27^\circ \text{C}$). If the thermos works so well for very hot liquids, why can cold water break it?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159260/ (and probably others)

Comment: Now you know the meaning of "old wives' tales."  She probably heard something once and took it as gospel, despite a complete lack of evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason why a thermos flask **may** break is when when you pour cold water into it while the glass is still hot. E.g. you empty a thermos flask that still contains some hot liquid, then immediately follow this up with cold water.

The phenomenon is called *thermal shock*. When the cold water hits the hot glass inner wall of the flask the glass starts cooling and shrinking due to thermal expansion (in reverse). But heat conduction takes time, so for a brief moment the inside of the glass wall is colder than the outside of the glass wall.

As a result the inside is contracting while the outside is not yet. This causes stress in the glass which in some cases leads to the glass cracking.

You can even demonstrate this using a small, cheap drinking glass. Heat it up in an over to about $150^\circ$ (Celsius) and prepare a water/ice bath. Gently drop the hot glass into the ice/water bath: chances are that it will shatter.

A cold thermos flask will not break when you pour cold water into it.

Note that it is by no means guaranteed that a thermos flask will break in these conditions. Local flaws, scratches or pre-existing micro-fissures in the glass probably initiate/exacerbate the breakage. Severity of the thermal shock (temperature difference), glass thickness and innate glass tensile strength also play a role.

Comment: Wouldn't the reverse not also break the glass? Poring hot liquid in while the glass is still cold?

Comment: @GyroGearloose: yes, it would, the phenomenon is the same. But either way, far from every thermos flask will break. It depends on temperature differences, thickness and glass strength.

Comment: Then why are there no warnings about filling hot liquids in? I feel there must be an additional, different effect at work.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: the phenomenon is well understood and people who work a lot with lab glassware (like me) have usually experienced it. Local flaws, scratches or pre-existing micro-fissures probably initiate/exacerbate it.

Comment: I don't doubt the thermal shock, but I doubt that this is the *only* reason here.

Comment: Btw. I somewhere heard that our stone age forefathers baked their stone tools to anneal them and make them less likely tho shatter.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: we do this with glass too. To improve strength of the glass it's kept a quite a high temperature for some time to 'anneal' it. That has nothing to do with thermal shock though.

Comment: "baking" will heal some of the micro-fissures and thus makes the material more resistant to shock (thermal or mechanical). But clearly, the annealing process as such does not have anything to do with thermal shock.

Comment: The experiment you suggest can be rather dangerous: dropping glass at 150°C into (cold) water without appropriate protective gear may result in the glass not simply cracking, but bits of glass flying into your eyes, cutting your hands, ... I am all for recommending hand-on experiments: but PLEASE give some warnings about the dangers of the experiment and appropriate precautions to take.

Comment: Also - note that glass breaks when a _tensile_ stress appears across a _stress concentrator_ (like a surface crack). Then consider whether "sudden cold" or "sudden hot" is more likely to create such tensile stress _on the surface likely to have a scratch_.

Comment: Take a look at Prince Rupert's Drop -- not an explanation or justification for this question, but a cool bit of science.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Rupert%27s_Drop