# Does a rapid temperature change crack annealed glass

Tags: temperature, water

Over at Lifehacks.SE there is [a question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/286/129) about how to remove ice from a windshield. [One answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/291/129) suggests using water but warns that using boiling water might crack the windshield.

As far as I understood it, the windshield is annealed to relieve the glass from internal stress, so it should withstand the rapid temperature change from -10°C (or so) to ~90°C (boiling, then carried outside and poured over ice, it should cool down a bit) just fine.

Is that correct? Should it be fine for the glass to pour boiling water over it?

Comment: You're analysis is wrong. The problem is that the hot water would cause localized heating which would cause stress.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/what-pressure-or-tension-occurs-in-a-glass-jar-when-i-pour-boiling-water-inside

Comment: @MaxW Okay, so if I manage to heat the whole glass at once it should be fine? Like not a little hot water, but a lot over the whole surface?

Comment: @dmckee I'll have to read that post more than once to comprehend. But thanks, I think I could calculate my answer from it.

Comment: You must also understand that a windshield is a very special glass laminate. It has two layers of glass with essentially a "plastic glue" in the middle. The idea is that an impact will cause the windshield to crack but not  break into pieces which would fly into the passenger compartment.