# Why should I discard a carafe if it has ever been heated empty? (Can thermal shock permanently weaken materials without causing them to fail?)

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, material-science

Related to "[What pressure or tension occurs in a glass jar when I pour boiling water inside?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/what-pressure-or-tension-occurs-in-a-glass-jar-when-i-pour-boiling-water-inside)"

I just got a new coffeemaker, and one of the warnings in the manual states that you should discard the (glass) carafe if it has *ever* been heated empty. As written, this means I should do so even if there is no outward damage to it. However, it's tempting to assume that the carafe is still safe to use if it isn't visibly damaged.

Does subjecting a carafe to this sort of thermal shock permanently weaken it without causing it to fail, even with no visible cracks or other damage? If so, how? (I'd want to suspect fatigue, but am I right and how would I explain this in the interest of safety to an ordinary person with a limited understanding of physics?)

Comment: It's sounds like the lawyer of the manufacturer is better at his job than the guys who made the glassware. If the glass is properly manufactured and tempered, there would be no need to do this, unless you had done something really extreme to it, like heat it on a gas stove and then bring it in contact with cold water. This does not mean that your assumption that visible cracks will form is correct. The glass may indeed fail without any obvious signs of thermal stress. I would take the warning seriously, as it probably indicates problems with the product in the past. Get a better product...

Comment: @CuriousOne: This is from a reputable brand (Mr. Coffee) and pretty much every carafe or other heat-resistant glass container of this sort that I've worked with bears a similar warning.

Comment: Someone in China printed "Mr. Coffee" on the glass that could have been made anywhere with any level of quality control or none. The stores who carry the brand, on the other hand, require that disclaimer. Neither is a guarantee for anything other than that the US consumer protection law keeps both lawyers and printers busy.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Chinese glass, e.g. borosilicate glass, comes in all price and quality ranges, like any other products. But this is about a Company engaging in excessive *rse covering and an over-zealous legal department.

Comment: @Gert: That's my point. No legal statement and no brand name are a guarantee for anything. Neither can the internal stress or the actual thermal stress history of a piece of glass be assessed easily by non-destructive experiments. If it breaks, it breaks. That's life.

Comment: I worked at a restaurant where a glass coffee pot boiled dry and shattered