# Is gradual cooling and reheating better than abrupt cooling then re-heating for material durability?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

So, I heated some bread on a pan (medium flame). Then, I turned the flame off knowing full well that I would put another bread on it within 10-15 seconds and heat it on medium flame again. I reasoned that the pan would be brought up to a high temperature again anyway, so better to let it cool gradually. Hence, I did not take the pan off the stove (which was still hot even though I had turned it off). My reasoning was that more extreme heating-cooling cycles will damage the material of the pan more than if it loses a smaller amount of its heat before having its temperature raised again.

However, others disagree with this saying it is better for the material if I take it completely off the stove and cool it down more violently before heating it up again.

Could someone please shed some light on what strategy might be better for the material?

Comment: Have you looked at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/what-pressure-or-tension-occurs-in-a-glass-jar-when-i-pour-boiling-water-inside?

Comment: Thanks! This seems to apply specifically to glass. Can the conclusions be extended to a Teflon-coated pan as well? Also, it deals specifically with water being poured into the glass.